# viewWillLayoutSubviews is being called recursively

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have view controller presented as a form sheet, in which there will be a table view with custom cell having a label on left and a textfield on right.

The form sheet size (height) will be dynamically increased based on the selection done from the options that will be given in the tableview.

So, for initial configuration, i use this

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

CGRect newBoundsForSuperView=CGRectMake(0, 0, max_view_width,max_view_height);
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.00")==YES)
{
    self.view.superview.bounds=newBoundsForSuperView;
    self.view.superview.center=self.view.window.center;
}
}
```

When I tap on the textfield, the viewWillLayoutSubviews is getting called infinite times and the application is getting freezed.

Can anyone point out what and/or where the problem is exactly ?

BTW, the issue is only in iOS 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your problem is related to setting `self.view.superview.bounds` which is causing the superview to call viewWillLayoutSubviews in a recursive manor.

Look into setting the `preferredContentSize` attribute of the view controller for iOS7+.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that helped me in solving the problem